# Notification for failed payment transaction

Tags: payment-processor

is there a way to get a notification of some kind for when a recurring payment hasn't gone through? Maybe with membership rules?
We've had it a couple of times now that payments haven't gone through for insufficient funds for example and we only find out about it by chance a few days later.

Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the Payment Processor you’re using. We have that option in the iATS Payments Extension and we can do that because its recurring payments are initiated/controled from within CiviCRM.

If you’re using another payment processing that processes a recurring contribution off-site and then notifies CiviCRM you will likely have to get into that Payment Processor’s admin/config and look for such a notification option.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that we use stripe as a payment processor

Comment: Can civicrm be configured to send out a notification to an admin if a grace period expires without payment being received?